# Changing the major mode of a named buffer

Tags: buffers, major-mode

How can I construct a function that changes the major mode of a named buffer ?

```
(defun change-buffer-mode (mode buffer)


)
```

Comment: `funcall` your functionʼs parameter `MODE` with current buffer set to `BUFFER`.  I guess this is not a duplicate question, because it's simply not worth asking…

Comment: Why does one have to pass the mode as  'org-mode, for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(defun change-buffer-mode (mode buffer)
 (with-current-buffer buffer (funcall mode)))
```

Comment: I call this with change-buffer-mode ('org-mode "Tika"). Why does one have to use quotation as in `'org-mode` ?

Comment: @Dilna: **You can try** what will happen if you don't add `quote`.

Comment: Emacs says `file-missing "Cannot open load file"`.  I try it but I also want to understand what happens.  Why are symbols needed ?

Comment: The question is "What does the calling code expect?" If it expects the value of variable `org-mode` then don't quote that symbol. If it expects the symbol itself then quote it. Lisp functions evaluate their arguments. (But macros and special forms don't necessarily evaluate arguments.)

Comment: The question is,  "Why does `funcall` expect `'org-mode` to set the major mode of a buffer to `org-mode` ?

Comment: `funcall` expects a **function**, in the sense of a Lisp object that satisfies `functionp` as first arg. *Ask Emacs*: [(elisp) What Is a Function](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/What-Is-a-Function.html).

Comment: Thus, what is `'org-mode`.  Naturally one wants to call the function `(org-mode)`.